# Turn on/off spring timer via api and be notified of it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, scheduler

My application contains many task that depends on schedulers as send reports via email, transfer data between databases, send data to another apis. But it's not always that all task have to be executed in same time.

My application is accessed by a front end rest client and I'd like to be able to turn on and turn off that timers and notify the clients about the changes.

I was thinking to use websocket to do the notification, but I've no idea how to create a scalable way to handle the timers.

Comment: Could you provide an example?